# lightning aura:if not working correctly

Tags: lightning-aura-components

`{!colHeader1 == objRecord.Column_Name__c}`

This is returning true but

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!colHeader1 == objRecord.Column_Name__c}">
```

this is not working. Means code within the if is not working.

Can any one help

Details: - 
I'm just printing {!colHeader1 == objRecord.Column_Name__c} this in teh component like :
`<aura:component>
    {!colHeader1 == objRecord.Column_Name__c}
<aura:component>`
this is printing true.

But -

`<aura:component>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!colHeader1 == objRecord.Column_Name__c}">
        abc
    </aura:if>
<aura:component>`

this is not printing **abc**.

Comment: Can you update your question with more information so that we can help you?

Comment: Hi Sanket I have edited the question with details... hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

I believe to reference any attribute in the lightning component you have to use {!v.} notation, not just {!}.

In your example, try:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.colHeader1 == v.objRecord.Column_Name__c}">
```

In a test I ran this:

```
<aura:attribute name="test" type="String" default="test"/>
{!test == 'test'} //this returns false
```

But:

```
<aura:attribute name="test" type="String" default="test"/>
{!v.test == 'test'} //this returns true
```

Comment: Sometimes it is those little things we take for granted... :-)